# Increase Speed of Hash Table for obscene amounts of data

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, hashmap

I am creating a hash table that sorts old stack overflow questions, YAY!. SO I store a word as the key, perhaps C++, then the ID number assoictated with the word and post. Mine works fine for "small" stack overflow files, I am able to add the words of about 400,000 questions, but the total is about 1.25 million. I need to store the data into one hashtable, but around the 400,000 mark the process of inserting table becomes so long as to be useless. Any ideas on how to modify the table or ways to restructure it. I breifly considered creating three lists of 400,000 and copying them all into one but that seemed like it would be time consuming, since after running succesfully, the main goal is to be as fast as humanely possible. Here is the code any help would be much appreciated. Warning: The code has gone through numerous changes and there is a lot of commented code

```
#ifndef HASH_H
#define HASH_H
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <list>
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

/*HashTable Node Class*/
template <typename K, typename V>
class HashNode{
private:

public:
    HashNode(K key, V value);
    HashNode* next;
    list<K> keys;
    list<V> values;
    K key;
    V value;

};

//Create node and insert key/value value
template <typename K, typename V>
HashNode<K,V>::HashNode(K key,V value){
   // this->value = value;
   // this->key = key;
    //this->next = NULL;
    list<K> keys;
    list<V> values;
}

/*HashTable Class*/
template <typename K, typename V>
class hashtable{
    private:
        HashNode<K,V>** array;
        int capacity;
        int size;

    public:
        hashtable();
        hashtable(int input);
        hashtable(const hashtable& input);
        int hashify(int key);
        int hashify(string key);
        void insert(K key, V value);
        void clear(int key);
        bool Search(int key);
        bool Search(string key);
        int getsize();
        void print();
        void resize();

};

//Hashtable Constructor
template <typename K, typename V>
hashtable<K,V>::hashtable(){
    capacity = 413158511;
    array = new HashNode<K,V>* [413158511];

    for(int i=0;i<capacity;i++)
        array[i] = NULL;
//16837687
    //20011603
    //24092093
    //30020381
    //104395301
}

//Hashtable Constructor
template <typename K, typename V>
hashtable<K,V>::hashtable(int input){
    capacity = input;
    array = new HashNode<K,V>* [input];

    for(int i=0;i<capacity;i++)
        array[i] = NULL;
//16837687
    //20011603
    //24092093
    //30020381
    //104395301
}

//HashTable Copy Constructor
template <typename K, typename V>
hashtable<K,V>::hashtable(const hashtable& input){
    capacity = input.capacity;
    size = input.size;
    array = new HashNode<K,V>* [capacity];
    HashNode<K,V>* temp;
    HashNode<K,V>* entry;
    HashNode<K,V>* entry2;
    for(int i=0;i<capacity;i++){
        if(input.array[i] != NULL){
        temp = new HashNode<K,V>(input.array[i]->key,input.array[i]->value);
        array[i] = temp;
        entry = input.array[i];
        entry2 = array[i];
        while(entry->next != NULL){
            entry = entry->next;
            entry2->next = new HashNode<K,V>(entry->key,entry->value);
            entry2 = entry2->next;
        }
        }
    }
}

//Resize Function
template <typename K, typename V>
void hashtable<K,V>::resize(){
    HashNode<K,V>** array2 = new HashNode<K,V>* [capacity*3];
    HashNode<K,V>* temp;
    HashNode<K,V>* entry;
    HashNode<K,V>* entry2;
    for(int i=0;i<capacity;i++){
        if(array[i] != NULL){
            temp = new HashNode<K,V>(array[i]->key,array[i]->value);
            array2[i] = temp;
            entry = array[i];
            entry2 = array2[i];
            while(entry->next != NULL){
                entry = entry->next;
                entry2->next = new HashNode<K,V>(entry->key,entry->value);
                entry2 = entry2->next;
            }
        }
    }
    capacity = capacity*3;
    array = new HashNode<K,V>* [capacity];
    for(int i=0;i<capacity;i++){
        if(array2[i] != NULL){
        temp = new HashNode<K,V>(array2[i]->key,array2[i]->value);
        array[i] = temp;
        entry = array2[i];
        entry2 = array[i];
        while(entry->next != NULL){
            entry = entry->next;
            entry2->next = new HashNode<K,V>(entry->key,entry->value);
            entry2 = entry2->next;
        }
        }
    }
}

//Create index for a key
template <typename K, typename V>
int hashtable<K,V>::hashify(int key){

    return key % capacity;
}

//Create index for a key with string
template <typename K, typename V>
int hashtable<K,V>::hashify(string key){
    //int temp;
  //  if( typeid(key).name() == typeid(temp).name() ){
        // unsigned int temp = accumulate(key.begin(),key.end(),0);
        // temp = temp % capacity;
    hash<string> strhash;
    return strhash(key)%capacity;
   // }
  //  else
     //   return key % capacity;
}

//INsert value to the table
template <typename K, typename V>
void hashtable<K,V>::insert(K key, V value){

    //if(size == capacity){
      //  resize();
    //}
    hash<string> strhash;
    int index = strhash(key)%capacity;

    if (array[index] == NULL){
        array[index] = new HashNode<K,V>(key,value);
        array[index]->keys.push_back(key);
        array[index]->values.push_back(value);
    }
    else{
        array[index]->keys.push_back(key);
        array[index]->values.push_back(value);
    }




   /* size++;
    hash<string> strhash;
    int index = strhash(key)%capacity;

    if (array[index] == NULL){
        array[index] = new HashNode<K,V>(key,value);
    }
    else {
      HashNode<K,V>* entry = array[index];


    while (entry->next != NULL)
        entry = entry->next;

    entry->next = new HashNode<K,V>(key,value);

    }*/

}

//Delete a value from the table
template <typename K, typename V>
void hashtable<K,V>::clear(int key){

    int index = hashify(key);

   // while(array[index] != NULL){
        //if(array[index]->key == key){
            //HashNode<K,V>* temp = array[index];

            //array[index] = dummy;
           // array[index]->key = NULL;
            //array[index]->value = NULL;
            array[index] = NULL;

            size--;
            //return temp->value;
        //}
       // index++;
      //  index %= capacity;
  //  }

    //return NULL;
}

//Find value in the table(int)
template <typename K, typename V>
bool hashtable<K,V>::Search(int key){
    int index = hashify(key);

   // while(array[index] != NULL){
        if(array[index]->key == key)
            return true;
        //index++;
        //index %= capacity;
   // }
    else
        return false;


}

//Find value in the table(string)
template <typename K, typename V>
bool hashtable<K,V>::Search(string key){
  /*  int index = hashify(key);

   // while(array[index] != NULL){
    if(array[index] == NULL)
        return false;
    else if(array[index]->key == key)
        return true;

     HashNode<K,V>* entry = array[index];


      while (entry->next != NULL){
          entry = entry->next;
          if(entry->key == key)
              return true;
        }

        return false; */
    hash<string> strhash;
    int index = strhash(key)%capacity;

    if(array[index] == NULL)
         return false;

   // key = final;
    //cout << key << end;
    //transform(key.begin(), key.end(), key.begin(), ::tolower);

  /*  wstring word(key.begin(),key.end());
    stemming::english_stem<> StemEnglish;
    StemEnglish(word);
    const std::string s(word.begin(),word.end());*/

    list<string>::iterator findIter = find(array[index]->keys.begin(),array[index]->keys.end(),key);

    if(findIter != array[index]->keys.end())
        return true;
    else
        return false;



}

//Return the size of the table
template <typename K, typename V>
int hashtable<K,V>::getsize(){
    return size;
}

//Print the contents of the table
template <typename K, typename V>
void hashtable<K,V>::print(){
    for(int i=0;i<capacity;i++){
        if(array[i] != NULL ){
            HashNode<K,V>* entry = array[i];
            while (entry != NULL){
                cout << "Key = " << entry->key << " Value = " << entry->value << endl;
                entry = entry->next;
            }
        }
    }
}












#endif // HASH_H
```

Comment: "Warning: The code has gone through numerous changes and there is a lot of commented code" - sigh!

Comment: "I am creating a hash table that sorts old stack overflow questions," - then I suspect you failed at step 1: hash tables aren't designed for sorting....grouping but not sorting

Comment: @MitchWheat sorry about it, you know how sometimes everything clicks, and what you type out in the next two hours is better than all of your hard dedicated work for the past three days? that was me

Comment: @MitchWheat that comes far far down the line, right now I am simply worrying about inputting it into the structure

Comment: Are you possibly running out of memory, causing much activity in the swap/page file by the OS?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm  I think so becaause of how much is being allocted for the nodes, and then a list in each node, I chose this because I could insert the fastest.

Comment: @zavier Why you are reinventing the wheel since hash table facility is already available in c++ in the form of std::unordered_map and it is pretty fast

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Suggestion: use a version control system such as git or subversion to track changes to your code, instead of commenting out lines.

Comment: You’d get better cache coherency and fewer heap allocations if your lists are `std::vector`, stored consecutively in memory, rather than linear linked lists. There are many other ways to avoid collisions, such as attempting to store a value that collides in a different empty bucket.

Comment: Second the advice about not reinventing the wheel, unless that’s the point of the learning exercise.

Comment: What you're trying to store isn't very concrete. 
 Say you have word "C++" as a key, you'd have some number and what?  A number like this question's 49951999 that you can append to  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/` to pull up the post?  A `unordered_multimap` (Standard or hand rolled) isn't a great container for this: you could have tens of thousands of values for the same key word, and every insertion would have to make its way along the list of existing values at that bucket comparing to see if already in the table.  How will you access/use the table?

Comment: If you basically just want to know the posts for the key word, and no you won't have duplicates in your input, try `std::unordered_map<std::string, vector<int>> x` and to insert just use `x[key_word].emplace_back(key_num, post_num)` - i.e. don't keep searching the `vector`.

Comment: The correct Google words are "inverted index"

Comment: @Tony Delroy the goal was to search for a word, C++, and find all the question ID’s associated with that word

Comment: @Davislor The goal of my data structures class is to make our own search engine with our own AVL tree and hash table, so I have to make my own and “reinvent the wheel” thankfully he is letting us use the hash function